# Large Vector Notation

Tags: notation, vectors, index-notation

Imagine I have an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and say it can be represented as
$$
\mathbf{v}=(v_1,...,v_n)^T
$$
where it's understood that the indexes are in increasing order. Imagine now the vector $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ obtained by simply removing entry with index $i$ of $\mathbf{v}$. What's the best (and most "economic") way to represent such vector? My idea was to simply interpret the vector as a sequence and write
$$
\mathbf{u}=\{v_j\}_{j\neq i}^T
$$
but I'm not sure whether this is correct and/or there is a better way of writing it. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I'm aware that
$$
\mathbf{u}=(v_1,...,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},...,v_n)^T
$$
can be used, but I was wondering whether a more "elegant" representation could be possible. If $i=1$ or $i=n$, in this notation, it is just strange that we included $v_1$ or $v_n$ in $\mathbf{u}$ in the first place. Purely an aesthetic preference, I know, but still.

Comment: $
\mathbf{u}=(v_1,...v_{i-1},v_{i+1},...,v_n)^T
$

Comment: $\mathbf u = (u_1,\dots,\widehat{u_i},\dots,u_n)^T$, hat also indicate omission of elements. Should I post it as an answer ?

Comment: @DaBler please see the edit.

Comment: Perhaps something like $\mathbf{u}=\left(u_n\right)_{1 \leq n \leq N, n \neq i}^T$

Comment: You can use what you're happy with, so long as you explain what you mean by it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If without writing any components perhaps for $\mathbf v \in \mathbb R^n$ you could write $\mathbf u = \mathbf v/e_i \in \mathbb R^{n-1}$, as a ''qoutient'', where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector in $\mathbb R^n$. I hope you know quotient spaces.

In some textbooks hats indicate the omission of elements
$$
\mathbb R^{n}/\text{span}\{e_i\} \cong \mathbb R^{n-1} \ni \mathbf v/e_i = (v_1,\dots,\widehat{v_i},\dots,v_n)^T = (v_1,\dots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\dots,v_n)^T
$$

Comment: I like this idea! Looks nice and neat and is easy to interpret (and least once it is defined).

Comment: thanks, I hope that the OP likes it too

Comment: Cool idea. Thanks! Yes, ultimately I feel we can do pretty much as we like, as long as we properly introduce our definitions.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it a lot in one text, I think defining an ad hoc notation could be useful. For example, I would consider using something simple like $\mathbf{v}^{(i)}$, $ \mathbf v^i$, or something similar. Otherwise, the comments and the other answer already give the standard notations I can think of.